# Finding algorithm to detect anomaly in non gaussian data

Tags: time-series, machine-learning

I have a data (time series like CPU, traffic and so on) that doesnt have a normal distribution usually (especially when I'm looking at 1 hour data).

Are there any algorithm to find anomalies?
I searched a lot but I found only algorithm related to data with normal distribution. I tried 3-sigma, box but have no success.

Currently I'm thinking about following approach:

```
- find today's trend
- get yesterday's data (may be smoothed with moving average)
- calculate the next point as averate between data from first and second step
- .. and I have no criteria to understand if current value is ok or anomaly.
```

So have two questions:

```
- are there any algorithm to use in my case?
- I'm on a right way with my approach or not?
```

thanks

Comment: Have you though about using already existing packages? Like this one, for example: https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series

Comment: There is a misconception that the data has to be normally distributed. Only residuals from the model have to be normally distributed if the model requires esp. if you are looking at p values, stander error and so on ....

Comment: @psarka, I tried tool from Twitter (R package) and Skyline tool. Both produce a lost of false positive, too much

Comment: @forecaster, could you please explain a little bit? As far as I understand you suggest to analyze derivatives characteristics of data like standard deviation or something else. thanks